# How to crop an image to 9 pieces

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an image and 9 small images. I would like to crop the image to 9 pieces and show them on 9 small images. I use Windows Phone 8. Could you have me ?

Thank you

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108661/split-an-image-into-several-pieces-silverlight-windows-phone

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić : Thank You but I dont know what type of sourceBitmap ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sourceBitmap is just another `WriteableBitmap`

For example, lets say we have this XAML (where bigImage is the Image we want to Crop)

```XAML
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="bigImage" Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png"></Image>                
        <Image x:Name="cropImage1"></Image>                
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then in the code behind

```C#
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

// using WriteableBitmapEx
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // create a WriteableBitmap with the bigImage as its Source
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)this.bigImage.Source);

    // calculate and crop
    WriteableBitmap crop1 = wb.Crop(0, 0, 100, 100);

    // set the cropImage1 image to the image that we just crop from the bigger one
    this.cropImage1.Source = crop1;            
}
```

---

If you want to see a great solution without using the WriteableBitmapEx (basically you gonna code your own Crop which returns a WriteableBitmap) then this webpage is for you:

[Crop Image Implementation](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/12/how-to-crop-image-using-writeablebitmap.html) (it's actually really easy to program, just need a tad bit of algebra)